# Self hosted wcf service inside wpf application - can't call / run through browser

Tags: wpf, wcf, service

I have hosted a WCF service inside the WPF application called "FaceDetectionService" which implements the interface IFaceDetectionService. I have hosted the service  using following code inside MainWindow's constructor:

```
    ServiceHost servicehostFaceDetectionRequired = new ServiceHost(typeof(FaceDetectionService));
    servicehostFaceDetectionRequired.Open();
```

Here's my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Kinect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.0.0" newVersion="1.8.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>      


          <service name="FacialRecognitionTest.FaceDetectionService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FacialRecognitionTest.IFaceDetectionService">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8734/Design_Time_Addresses/FacialRecognitionTest/FaceDetectionService/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Problem: After starting the application I can't browse to my URI which I gave in App.config. I did same steps for my self-hosted WCF Service for Windows Form Application and it is working. Can anybody help please.

Thanks

Comment: is there an error you get?

Comment: No I am not getting any error but I just can't call service and can't browse it in web browser to test.

Comment: update: I tried to test service using WCF client and got the following error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. I was closing the service before Closing the window.